# How can I bind `C-c C-j` to always do `org-journal-new-entry`?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-journal

I did:

```lisp
(use-package org-journal
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq org-journal-dir "~/org/journal/"
        org-journal-date-format "%A, %d %B %Y"
        org-journal-time-format "%I:%M %p"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'org-journal-new-entry)
```

in my `init.el` file. However, `C-c C-j` seems to be bound to `org-goto` instead of `C-c C-j` for some reason. Why is this?

I got this idea from: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") 'ivy-resume)` suggested in the Ivy docs and wanted to have a similar global shortcut to get into Org Journal. What is the best way to do this?u

Comment: Try `C-c j` instead.  The `C-c <letter>` bindings are reserved for users but the `C-c C-<letter>` bindings are available for packages and are used by them, especially ones like `org` with huge keymaps.  If you really want `C-c C-j`, look into `bind-key*`.

Comment: See [Keybinding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html#Key-Binding-Conventions) in the Emacs Lisp manual as well.

Comment: @FranBurstall Hmm, yes I know the convention that `C-c C-<letter>` is reserved for  packages, but I never really use `org-goto`, not sure what it even does. I will look into this  `bind-key*` however. Not sure if there would be any actual disadvantage. Also the recommended setup in [Ivy mode](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper#small-config-example) includes various `C-c C-<letter>` and also various `C-c <letter>` keybindings, so I'm not sure if any conventions are being broken here. Somewhat confused.

Comment: Any mode-specific keymap has a preference over the global keymap and thus setting `"C-c C-j"` in the global keymap works only in modes that don't set that keybinding in their own keymap. You can make "C-c C-j" in org-mode buffers with `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'org-journal-new-entry)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `use-package` to force your keybinding.

```
(use-package org-journal
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq org-journal-dir "~/org/journal/"
        org-journal-date-format "%A, %d %B %Y"
        org-journal-time-format "%I:%M %p")
  :bind* ("C-c C-j" . org-journal-new-entry))
```